# How is instance of FacesContext created inspite of it being abstract

Tags: java, jsf-2

FacesContext is an Abstract Class and as far as my knowledge is concerned we cannot create instance of an Abstract Class.
so, 
when I do FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() 
how am I getting instance?

Comment: Well, List is an Interface but yeah u r right about the phenomenon.
and as far as I discovered, 
we r not creating an Instance of the class  by calling this method; instead we r just getting the instance that is already associated with that particular request.
and List was a good reminder. 
Any other useful information/ suggestion about this would 
be highly appreciable.

Comment: @BalusC, Bauke your example is totally different case: List doesn't have equivalent for `getInstance` method. `java.util.Calendar` is good example. It is abstract class and has `getInstance` method. Calendar  is instantiated as GregorianCalendar. Same mechanism should be used for FacesContext.

Comment: @user3462765 See [FacesContext source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/2.1.0/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.java)

Answer (score 0):

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns instance of **FacesContext subclass** (which is *not abstract class*), for example it is FacesContextImpl in MyFaces.

---

We have similar situation with *abstract class* java.util.Calendar: getInstance method returns instance of GregorianCalendar.